# how to put condition in Table column in .JS based on another column Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to .js, i want to add hyper link to column name tag when there is some number in tag field else want to keep String as None.
how should i use if condition in Column below to so if it column it will call GerritFormater() method else keep text as it is.

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='tag' filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } } dataSort={true} width='100'>DisplayTag</TableHeaderColumn>

function GerritURL(gerrit, i) {
  return (<a key={i} href={"https://some-url/" + gerrit}>{gerrit} </a>);
}

function GerritFormatter(cell, row) {
  return GerritURL(cell, 0);
}

function StateFormatter(cell, row) {
  return (
    <div>
    <a data-tip={row.detailed_state}>{cell}</a>
    <ReactTooltip place="top" type="dark" effect="solid"/>
    </div>
  );
}

class GetTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.options = {
        defaultSortName: 'state',  // default sort column name
        defaultSortOrder: 'asc'  // default sort order
      };
  }

  render() {
    var results=this.props.results
    var index=this.props.index
    return (
      <div>
      <BootstrapTable ref='table' hover bodyStyle={ { border: 'rgb(0,70,100) 1px solid'} } headerStyle={ { border: 'black 1px solid', backgroundColor: '#d0c9d1' } } data={ results[index].data } options={ this.options } condensed exportCSV>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='number' filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } } isKey={true} dataSort={true} width='60' dataFormat={GerritFormatter}>Gerrit</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='state' filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } } dataSort={true} width='120' dataFormat={StateFormatter}>State</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='tag' filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } } dataSort={true} width='100'>DisplayTag</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

her I attached Snapshot [Whenever the State contain 'Gerrit is Promoted', corresponding 'Tag' filed will be added hyperlink with GerritFormatter method but if state contain other than Gerrit is promoted, it will only put tag field as it as mentioned in the link is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV9qN.png)

Comment: Not to be rude, but I am really struggling with this one: *how should i use if condition in Column below to so if it column it will call GerritFormater() method else keep text as it is.* I simply don't understand it.

Comment: Hi ,In TextHeaderColumn field of 'dataField='tag'' value, some Value are numeric(C-Number) and some values are Simple String. I am looking for adding Hyperlink to the Numeric value in this column Field, but not for the String(non-numeric) value.  we have one method GerritFormatter() which basically add Hyperlink to the number. but i am not sure if i can use if Condition in the TextheaderCloumn of dataField='tag''. if so could you tell me the syntax inside the column field?, I hope my question clarify your context

Comment: Are you wondering how to use a condition here: `....dataSort={true} width='100'>{YOUR_CONDITION}</TableHeaderColumn>`?

Comment: Hi Attached the Snapshot of table fields. here I want to add hyperlink to Display-Tag field if State field contain "Gerrit is Promoted" ,display-Tag field print text as it is if state field is other then "Gerrit is Promoted".
currently I am using if (result['state'] == "Gerrit is promoted") { <execute above retun code with Display-tag filed modified with dataformat={gerritformtter} ------> this link add Hyper link to the number mentioned in the display-tag field and in else part i am keeping above condition as it is . but my code is going into else condition. clue what wrong in the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve this with issue with adding dataformat function and in function i used condiation if cell is number with regex then execute else do normal function.

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='tag' filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } } dataSort={true} width='150' dataFormat={TagFormatter}>DisplayTag</TableHeaderColumn>

function TagFormatter(cell, row) {
 if (row.tag.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
   return GerritURL(cell,0);
}
```